# for loop in Shiny htmlOutput does not execute in order

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

This is a really strange behaviour for using loop inside a Shiny htmlOutput. What I've been trying to do is very simple, execute a Javascript code (console.log) from the Shiny htmlOuput and print the loop number to the console. See code below:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
  mainPanel(htmlOutput("result"))
)
server<-  function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$goButton,{
    output$result <- renderUI({
      html_output_list <- lapply(1:50, function(j) {
        htmlname <- paste("html", j, sep="")
        htmlOutput(htmlname)
      })
      # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
      # to display properly.
      do.call(tagList, html_output_list)
    })
    lapply(1:14, function(i){ 
        htmlname <- paste("html", i, sep="")
        output[[htmlname]] <- reactive({
          paste('<script>number=',
                            i,
                            ';console.log(number);</script>')
          })
        })
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

By clicking the go button, the result should be an ordered sequence number from 1 to 14 (as the number i loops from 1 to 14), but the actual outcome is 14,1,2,...,13. Try the range of i from 1:20 will generate a sequence as (14,15,16,17,18,1,19,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,20,9,10,11,12,13). Could anyone explain what's going on here? How come it does not follow the order? Obviously it's neither a random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

app:R

```
   library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)
    ui <- tagList(
            useShinyjs(),
            fluidPage(
            actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
            mainPanel(
                     uiOutput("result")
    )))
    server<-  function(input, output) {

            observeEvent(input$goButton, {
                lapply(1:50, function(j){

                        shinyjs::logjs(paste('number=', j))
                    })

            })

    }
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This may give the right answer, but it is slightly different from my purpose. You finished the loop by assigning the Javascript to an array (x) before output. Is it possible to output inside the loop? My code is to achieve this, but the execution does not follow the right order. Thanks.

Comment: Try with the shinyjs package, with the logjs function. Check the modified answer.